# Python printing query in R Markdown using Reticulate

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

I'm using python in R markdown to just test how well it works for future work. However everytime I run a python cell I get this message in red. In the case of for loops it only produces the red text and not the print.

[image]

````
```{python}
x = [1, 2, 3]
for i in x:
  print(i)
```
````

```
Output:
Python 3.9.5 (C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe)
Reticulate 1.20 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Have you tried `{python, message=FALSE}`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks that got rid of the message! Weirdly I found that the for loops don't produce output to console until I run another cell is there a way around this?

Comment: I used your for loop and got output in the Rmarkdown console, not sure why your for loop is not displaying the "print(i)" portion

Comment: I found I have to manually quit the loop using cntrl + z + enter after running the cell for an output to produce